# How do I upgrade my mongodb version from db version v2.6.10 to version 3.4.7 and make a symlink thats in my path enviromnent variable?

Tags: linux, mongodb

I already downloaded the 3.4.7 version from the mongodb download center in my downloads directory by doing `wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-3.4.7.tgz` and then I extracted the archive using `-tar zxvf linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-3.4.7.tgz` and then to make a symlink in my path enviromnent variable I did `echo $PATH` which showed `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

and then I tried to make a symlink to the usr/local/bin/mongod path by doing this `sudo ln -$ ~/Downloads/mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-3.4.7.tgz /usr/local/bin/mongod` but when I do this it says `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/mongod': File exists` but when  I type `mongod --version` it says I'm using db version 2.6.1 instead of the version 3.4.7 that I downloaded. I tried doing the `sudo apt update` and sudo apt upgrade commands but It doesn't update my db version to the version I originally downloaded. I am very new to this and I don't really understand what these commands exactly do, but can anyone please help me figure out how to get mongodb3.4.7 version instead of version 2.6.10? I would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: What about installing version from *artful* https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/mongodb-server

Comment: Put simply, ***You risk data loss when updating from 2.6 to 3.4 directly***. As per the release notes of each and every version in between, you need to update to the next higher version step by step